# Getting lines from files

Tags: python

I am trying to get `a` to be the first line of the `file` and `b` to be the second.

This prints nothing.

```
f = open(filename)
line = f.readline().strip()
while line:
    a = f.readline()
    b = f.readline()
    line = f.readline()
print(a)
print(b)
```

I want to assign specific lines to variables, not just read all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: not really thats just add all lines into list

Comment: Why do you have the `while` loop? What's it for?

Comment: to read each line

Comment: But you are also doing that with `readline`. Are you actually trying to iterate the whole file three lines at a time, or do you just want the first and second lines as you state in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Check the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) first please, it says:

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use
>   list(f) or f.readlines().

```
lines = f.readlines()
a = lines[0]
b = lines[1]
```

Comment: @James, please accept the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines =[]
with open(filename) as f:
    i =0
    for line in f:
        lines[i] = line
        i += 1

print '1st Line is: ', lines[0]
print '2st Line is: ', lines[1]
```